# Setar célula de arquivo *.CSV como mesclada

Tags: java, csv, groovy

É possível setar que uma determinada célula seja mesclada em uma arquivo *.csv gerado? Pergunto pois estou gerando um arquivo *.csv onde o usuário deverá apenas fazer um `Ctrl + C` \ `Ctrl + v` no conteúdo e colar em uma planilha padrão, porém essa planilha padrão possui a célula como mesclada onde será colado o esse conteúdo e eu não posso modificar isso na planilha padrão então por esse motivo a necessidade.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
Logger logger= Logger.getLogger("org.bonitasoft");

logger.info(suprimentosDevolvidos.toString())

BufferedWriter strW = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\TESTE\\suprimentos.csv"), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));

strW.write("QUANTIDADE TOTAL LOTE: "+quantidadeTotalLote.toString()+"\n")
strW.write(suprimentosDevolvidos.toString())
strW.close();
```

Comment: você quer formatar o arquivo CSV de tal forma, que ao colar o texto do arquivo no excel ( planilha padrão? ) o excel mescle uma célula?

Comment: Acho que é mais fácil trabalhar direto com XLS não? Por que é meio complicado trabalhar com um arquivo **texto** dessa forma.

Comment: @ErickWeil exatamente

Comment: @GustavoCinque concordo com você, porém como já possuo o código para gerar o arquivo *.csv pronto queria ver se havia um modo de não perder todo o trabalho

Comment: No meu entendimento não há como mesmo @R.Santos, tem que utilizar xls.

Comment: @GustavoCinque e em xls, tu teria algum exemplo para me mostrar?

Comment: Lamento amigo, não posso compartilhar os códigos que utilizo, não são nem meus, per se. O que eu posso fazer é [isso](https://gist.github.com/madan712/3912272), encontrar algo que te possa fazer caminhar, e [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716032/merging-cells-in-excel-using-apache-poi), encontrar algo que resolva sua duvida.

Comment: Espero que consiga resolver. Mesmo. Já passei por vários apuros com xls, xlsx, etc.